# How to duplicate "Pages" section in the control panel?

Tags: customization, pages

I want to create my own custom page (gallery) tab like PAGES in the control panel. Its help me to organize the gallery pages under "Gallery" name. How can I do this? I can do this with custom posts but this time templates won't shown up. :/ Actually I want to exactly copy of the "Pages" and name it "Gallery". Then I create my custom pages under it. Hope you'll understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should fairly closely mimic "Pages".

```
function gallery_type_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 
        'public' => true, 
        'label' => 'Gallery',
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array( 
               'title', 
               'editor', 
               'thumbnail', 
               'excerpt', 
               'page-attributes', 
               'custom-fields' 
      )
    );
    register_post_type( 'Gallery', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gallery_type_custom_init' );
```

If you need this to use your [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template), though, it won't work. [That part is hard-coded for `page` post types only.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L659)

Comment: Thanks for response. I did this but as I said; when I did this page templates can't shows. I want to use this custom sections with my custom page template. How to integrate it?

Comment: And as I said, custom page templates only work with "page" post types. That is hard-coded into the WordPress core. It might be possible to hijack that functionality but you are better off using some other mechanism, like custom post meta.